# Get child class variable in parent class

Tags: php, oop

I've two classes in 2 files.
First (parent.php):

```
class Parent{
   var $ParentVar;
}
```

Second (child.php):

```
class Child{
   var $ChildVar = 'im a childvar';
}
```

How can I set `$ChildVar` value to `$ParentVar` for printing 'im a childvar' in Parent class?

Comment: Make an instance of the child in the constructor of the parent and then set the childvar to parentvar?!

Comment: Are you using any kind of inheritance or anything that relates an Child and Parent? Or are this purely standalone classes?

Comment: Read PHP documentation about Objects here is not a School place..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to use inheritance correctly, so:

```
class Child extends Parent {
```

Secondly, you should never be accessing the value of a Child from the parent. What you could do, is to define an abstract function in the Parent class which the Child needs to implement, and then code in the Parent could then call the Child's function. For example:

```
abstract class Parent {
    abstract protected function returnSomeValue();
    public function outputSomeValue() {
        return $this->returnSomeValue();
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    protected $ChildVar = 'im a childvar';
    protected function returnSomeValue() {
        return $this->ChildVar;
    }
}
```